# I run OpenWhisk on Docker Compose according to the docs instructions, but still I can't use OpenWhisk CLI to create any actions

Tags: docker, docker-compose, deployment, serverless, openwhisk

I followed the instructions in the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/openwhisk-devtools/blob/master/docker-compose/README.md) to download this preset they created for easily running Apache OpenWhisk for development purposes on Docker Compose.

I use `make run` which works fine. Then `make hello-world` will run the example action just as fine.

I read the `.wskprops` file to see that it's running it in port `9090` and the auth value is `23bc46b1-...:123zO3...`. So I use `wsk property set --apihost localhost:9090 --auth 23bc46...`.

But if I try using `wsk action create someAction main.js` to create my own action it returns `Unable to create action 'someAction': Put "https://localhost:31001/api/v1/namespaces/_/actions/test?overwrite=false": dial tcp [::1]:31001: connect: connection refused`.

These are the steps the Makefile appears to follow.

I'm not sure if perhaps I'm missing a step? How do I link running it and using it? The documentation doesn't seem to specify this. My knowledge of Docker Compose is naught, but I need to run this with the time I have available, I hoped this would be a simple solution. I've been stuck trying to run OpenWhisk in my local computer for a week, so any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I got into the Makefile and printed `WSK_CLI` to discover that it was using `docker-compose/openwhisk-src/bin/wsk` instead of my own installation of `wsk`.

So essentially, after running `make run`, I can create an action using `./openwhisk-src/bin/wsk action -i create <action_name> <action.js>`. Note that the `-i` is needed to get over the security simplifactions of running it locally for development purposes.

Comment: Hi, after successful deployment of openwhisk via docker-compose, how can we access function playground? does this functionality with docker-compose deployment but I dont seems to access it.